# How to assoicate a SP2010 SPD workflow to a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I need to copy a SPD workflow from Test to Production environment. I connect to two site using two SPD window and then C&P the workflow over. It seems most of the workflow content is moved correctly beside I cannot associate the destination workflow to a list. I have tried update the GUID inside .xoml.wfconfig.xml file to the new list GUID. However it seems no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is advisable to create a reusable workflow from designer, if you want to move to another site.

If you have created list workflow, here is good article that demonstrates step by step guidelines to move SP designer list workflow from one site to another site.

https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/